# Typescript: How to make intelissence work with conditional generics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I open this post for a technical question about typescript. I have this type below:

```
export type ButtonVariant = "solid" | "light" | "outline" | "ghost" | "link" | "highlight";

type OutlineVariantProps = { backgroundColor?: string };
type SolidGhostVariantProps = { isHighlightOnActive?: boolean };

export type VariantProps<T extends ButtonVariant> = T extends "outline" ? OutlineVariantProps : T extends "ghost" | "solid" ? SolidGhostVariantProps : never;

export type ButtonProps<T extends ButtonVariant = "solid"> = {
    variant?: T;
    variantProps?: VariantProps<T>;
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

Thanks to this code, it allows me to have conditionals on the variantProps field when instantiating the component like below :

```
 <Button variant="outline" variantProps={{ backgroundColor: ... }} />
 <Button variant="ghost" variantProps={{ isHighlightOnActive: ... }} />
```

But when in the code I want to test the case of variantprops in which I am located, the intelissense does not know what to show me.

If i do this :

```
if(variant === "props" && variantProps.[...])
```

I would like that intelissense tell me what is available behind variantProps.
Do you have any tips about this ?

I did not try nothing, because i don't really now what i can do.

Comment: Narrowing generics is not an easy task for the compiler. Are you okay to go without generics? I can suggest something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weakKw)

Comment: That's amazing, and that's perfect for the use case. thanks you for this answer !

Comment: welcome, will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowing generics is a tough challenge and has no good solution to it.

The easiest solution here would be to go without generics and for that, we would need a dictionary where the keys would be variants and the values variant props:

```
type VariantPropsMap = {
  solid: SolidGhostVariantProps;
  ghost: SolidGhostVariantProps;
  outline: OutlineVariantProps;
  link: never;
  highlight: never;
  light: never;
};
```

Now, by using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we will create an object with the shape of {`variant: 'some variant', variantProps: someProps}` and then we will take all its values, which will result in a *union* with the correct types:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

export type ButtonProps = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof VariantPropsMap]: { variant?: K; variantProps: VariantPropsMap[K] };
}>
```

`ButtonProps`:

```
type ButtonProps = {
    variant?: "solid" | undefined;
    variantProps: SolidGhostVariantProps;
} | {
    variant?: "light" | undefined;
    variantProps: never;
} | {
    variant?: "outline" | undefined;
    variantProps: OutlineVariantProps;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
```

Usage:

```
export type ButtonProps = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof VariantPropsMap]: { variant?: K; variantProps: VariantPropsMap[K] };
}> &
  React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  if (props.variant === 'solid') {
    const a = props.variantProps.isHighlightOnActive;
  }
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4AhAVxhggDsA1FFGApe8ALwEAzhAA2wACb44AHwLyA5gAsYytfghd5vJHoLaIU3avXBeAazP4twbZp1lKTFnADyRuyRBYVEYAAUcMCk4SQBvOAAjdHsNHA5eBQBhOWgAfgAuOCthXg04AF8Kb1YAZTlFAHEtSxhgkTEIiCiYuHjgKQAJVy13GF9eAEEMYAA3JALEiDlUXgqKcmq4NtDOqIBZFDAe2PI4IvqFQrr5BSaW7Y7IqQoziysri7urB-Cnl7hDDBjEhCv4gYEfrtnqc4MZ7IUTHMoP8XG5hjAEUgkf9RpjseRKl5mKxBLIOEhfJgADwAFQAfD0aQBtexIRgQTBwGkAXXWNDo8E2nG4fChPVJ5MpVJOZyZAGk4HY4Kz2ZzIU8DmBuYV4jMhO0YAs5aQ4HqQo8ulJCurLZr5dy1gSGQAyGHIdAwAB0wp4vAGNL2ABkJtxhAkuEgpFT-UGfXwAKKyJAgJBiOnrNB8KzsLi+noACjAT0Kcd4UIAlDEGTLFZzC09PWaDTFxJJ8DIbvhKzWzpneNmUD0i5bG-qdg3+kM0doxpNpnN-uUCRQgA)

Comment: Thank you again about this, my code feel like more readable !